# UISegmentedControl Selected value is missing in UITableView during scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UITableView` with around 15 cells. In each cell, there is a `UISegmentedControl`.

When user selected a value of `UISegmentedControl` in the first cell, scroll down and scroll back to the first cell. The selected value is missing.

I found that it called `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` frequently. While the cell dismissed from the screen, it will call `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` again when the cell is back to the screen. And the selected value of the `UISegmentedControl` is reset.

I am currently using iOS8, and I don't have any problem with previous iOS version.

Thank you very much.

Ben

Comment: share code what you are doing in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple calls for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is normal, the app dequeues offscreen cells. Make sure you save the state of the `UISegmentedControl` and update the segmented control appropriately in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the next time it appears onscreen.